# opnet 14.5 environment variable configuration for visual studio 2015 on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, environment-variables, windows-10, opnet

My problem here is I couldn't find the environment variable configuration for Opnet modeler 14.5 for visual studio 2015 on my windows 10. I already tried the environment variable settings for visual studio 2010 with some necessary changing such as location. But it is not working.

Import these 12 system variables:

1. DevEnvDir C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE;
2. Framework35Version v3.5;
3. FrameworkDir C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework;
4. FrameworkVersion v2.0.50727;
5. INCLUDE C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include;
6. LIB C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib;
7. LIBPATH C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Fra mework\v2.0.50727;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB;
8. Path ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;C:\WINDOWS\Micr osoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin;

Notice: probably this variable already exists in your variables. For the ones like this, remember to write the first semicolon (;).

9. VCINSTALLDIR C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC
10. VS100COMNTOOLS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
11. VSINSTALLDIR C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
12. WindowsSdkDir C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A;

This are environment variables for visual studio 2010

Comment: no one? no answer for this question? I don't use windows but How?

Answer (score 1):

According to this page [splash](https://splash.riverbed.com/docs/DOC-4633) visual studio 2015 has not supported yet. but you can try [this](https://supportkb.riverbed.com/support/index?page=content&id=S20843) for Visual studio 2015 
But here it is what I have done to fix the problem:
as mentioned in the question there are many variables and you need to adapt them with Microsoft VS 2015 it's quiet easy:
Open Microsoft VS command prompt under start and find it for native purpose.
then any variable that you can update any variable that you mentioned in the question by typing set variable for example `set include` will generate the values for include variable adapted to VS 2015. then you change the environment variable and values you might just need to change `include` and `path`. then open `cmd` if you have fixed the problem `cl` command should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simple way to set up the environment for Modeler. There are several batch files for setup the compiler environment.

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64
"C:\Riverbed\18.0\sys\pc_amd_win64\bin\modeler.exe" -env_db "C:\Users\Allen C. Kim\op_models\Next_Gen_Sat_II\next_gen_sat-18-0.prefs"
```

Here is my actual batch file for my current project. The second line is to setup the environment for compiler. You don't need to edit the "Environment" in Windows.